# Multiple curves on Same zedgraph plot

Tags: c#, serial-port, zedgraph

I am trying to read in data from two serial ports, and plot each curve over time, on the same graph.  However, when I do this, it connects the curves.  How do I keep the two data sets separate but on the same graph?  I've seen a lot of solutions using masterPane, however, when I try to use it, my program says that there is no materpane in zedgraph.

Here is the relevant code:

```
GraphPane myPane2;
PointPairList Oz1time = new PointPairList();

myPane2 = zedGraphControl2.GraphPane;
myPane2.Title = "Data vs Time Plots";
myPane2.XAxis.Title = "Elapsed Minutes";
myPane2.YAxis.Title = "Ozone Data";

        private void UpdateData3(string line)
    {
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.BeginInvoke(new UpdateDataDelegate(UpdateData3), new object[] { line });
        }
        else
        {
            if (chk_DISPLAY_3.Checked == true)
            {
                timer3.Interval = (30000);
                timer3.Start();
                OZ1lastdatatime = DateTime.Now;
                count++;
                if (count > 7)
                {
                    count = 0;
                    TextBox_3.Text = "";
                    TextBox_3.AppendText(line);
                }
                else
                {
                    TextBox_3.AppendText(line);
                }
            }
            if (chk_SAVE_FILE_3.Checked == true)
            {
                StoreData3.Write(line);
                StoreData3.Flush();
            }
            if (chk_PLOT_1.Checked == true)
            {
                string[] blahArray = line.Split(new char[] { ',' });
                //string blaharray = Convert.ToDouble(blahArray[2]).ToString("F4");
                int column_data = Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text);
                double oz1 = Convert.ToDouble(blahArray[column_data]);
                //TextBox_3.Text = Convert.ToString(oz1);
                TimeSpan span = DateTime.UtcNow - startDateTimeOfProgram;
                double elapsedMinutes = span.TotalMinutes;

                Oz1time.Add(elapsedMinutes,oz1);
                zedGraphControl2.AxisChange();
                zedGraphControl2.GraphPane.AddCurve("", Oz1time , Color.Blue);
                zedGraphControl2.Refresh();



            }
        }
    }

   private void UpdateData4(string line)
    {
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.BeginInvoke(new UpdateDataDelegate(UpdateData4), new object[] { line });
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(line);
            if (chk_DISPLAY_4.Checked == true)
            {
                timer4.Interval = (30000);
                timer4.Start();
                OZ2lastdatatime = DateTime.Now;
                count++;
                if (count > 7)
                {
                    count = 0;
                    TextBox_4.Text = "";
                    TextBox_4.AppendText(line);
                }
                else
                {
                    TextBox_4.AppendText(line);
                }
            }
            if (chk_SAVE_FILE_4.Checked == true)
            {
                StoreData4.Write(line);
                StoreData4.Flush();
            }
            if (chk_PLOT_2.Checked == true)
            {
                string[] blahArray = line.Split(new char[] { ',' });
                //string blaharray = Convert.ToDouble(blahArray[2]).ToString("F4");
                int column_data = Convert.ToInt32(textBox4.Text);
                double oz2 = Convert.ToDouble(blahArray[column_data]);
                //TextBox_3.Text = Convert.ToString(oz1);
                TimeSpan span = DateTime.UtcNow - startDateTimeOfProgram;
                double elapsedMinutes = span.TotalMinutes;

                Oz1time.Add(elapsedMinutes, oz2);
                zedGraphControl2.AxisChange();
                zedGraphControl2.GraphPane.AddCurve("", Oz1time, Color.Green);
                zedGraphControl2.Refresh();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem appears to be that you are using the same `PointPairList`, `Oz1time`, to create both curves.  Instead, try creating two separate `PointPairList`s, one for each curve.

Some relevant code bits:

```
PointPairList Oz2time = new PointPairList();
...
Oz2time.Add(elapsedMinutes, oz2);
...
zedGraphControl2.GraphPane.AddCurve("", Oz2time, Color.Green);
```

Comment: Thank you! How come c# doesn't recognize the masterpane command? I'm also trying to is OZ1time.IsY2Axis = true; to add another y axis, however c# says that IsY2Axis doesn't exist

Comment: I know nothing about "masterpane".  About the Y axis, you first need to create one, like this: `int idx = zedGraphControl2.GraphPane.AddY2Axis("Other Stuff")`;

Comment: Thanks for the help, for some reason visual studio doesn't recognize the commands: IsY2Axis or AddY2Axis